# Magento Mass Add Products

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Is there a way in Magento to mass add products from say spreadsheet or word file or some other  method? Im looking to mass add say 1000 Products even it was just the title and SKU anything would be helpful. I have tried the import and export but it freezes up and ends up messing up my database.

Any Help?

Magento Version 1.6

Comment: https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport

Comment: Hmm seems a bit confusing but i will give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here seems to work it takes a while to setup the CSV format but will work.

http://www.meteorify.com/2012/05/importing-product-images-csv-magento-1-7-0-0/

Answer (score 1):

I think that the solution is to create csv file and then import products from it.

But be sure that you've create a proper csv file. Most import errors are because of errors in csv file.

Undoubtedly, the best way to get into the requirements is to have a model pattern. There is a simple way to get it. All you need to do is to export some products from your store into a comma delimited file.

To do that click System in your Admin Panel and then Export in the Import and Export menu. Then you are to choose products from the Entity Type drop-down. Now, the system creates a list of product attributes. All the attributes export into the .csv file, that is why you can click Continue to export the products you have selected. Now, you can open your file in any of your favorite spreadsheet application and use it as an example for your own .csv.

**How to import csv file to Magento**

There are several things you are to remember while creating your import .csv. Put every new product on a new line and the attributes which you define should be divided by commas. All the attributes should be in the same order as the first row.

In case you are editing your products in Microsoft Excel each product will be placed on a new line. The attributes which you define will fall into the column that is listed in the very first row.

Note that it is very important to select Yes (to leave out incompatible features), when Excel asks you what file format you wish to save.